# BibLaTeX, vim-latex and \xxxcites

Tags: biblatex, vim-latex

He, the vim-latex module for vim, provides a very nice feature: inserting a reference with the `F9` key, which opens a window where you can look for the reference to insert. However, it does not seem to be fully working with the biblatex `\footcites` command, especially when using `prenote` or `postnote` arguments.

Below is a MWE indicating when it works and when it does not.

```
\footcite[p]{}%F9 here works
\footcite{Boismard2000}{}%f9 here works
\footcites[i]{Boismard2000}[is]{Boismard2000}{Boismard2000}%F9 here works
\footcites(S){}%Here doesn't work
\footcites{Boismard2000}{Boismard2000}{Boismard2000}[somepage]{}%F9 here doesn't work
```

Any idea how to solve the last problem?